# PHP - How to extract content from a div via Regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a string of HTML where some inherited `div` present and I need to extract only the top level div, for example-

```
$html= '<div class="test">
            <div>
                <div>Some text 1</div> 
                <div>Image content 2</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>Some text 2</div> 
                <div>Image content 2</div>
            </div>
            ....
        </div>';
$regex ='/<div\sclass=[\"\']test[\"\']>.*?<\/div>/is';
preg_match($regex, $html, $matches);
```

But the real problem is the result shows me only the first `Some text 1</div>`, Please help me to figure out where I made the mistakes?

I need to grab the entire class `test` 'div' as a result matches.

```
<div>
    <div>Some text 1</div> 
    <div>Image content 2</div>
</div>
<div>
     <div>Some text 2</div> 
     <div>Image content 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A best practice would be to parse the html using a library and extract what you need. From the official documentation, try [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: @DanIonescu, I am using the file_get_content and then using the regular expression I want to grab those form.

Comment: if you insist, try the regex: <div class="test">([\s\S]((.|\n)*))<\/div>  you can excape it where necessary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The following *regex* should do it :

```
(?s)(?<=<div\sclass="test">\n).*(?=<\/div>)
```

*see* **[*demo / explanation*](https://regex101.com/r/I6uRtU/1)**

**PHP**

```
<?php
$regex = '/(?s)(?<=<div\sclass="test">\n).*(?=<\/div>)/';
$str = '<div class="test">
            <div>
                <div>Some text 1</div>
                <div>Image content 2</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>Some text 2</div>
                <div>Image content 2</div>
            </div>
            ....
        </div>';
preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```