# Extract Content of outermost Div with PHP and Regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract content of a div with PHP, independent of a class name and other parameters.

What I need is, I have multiline, single line, multiple parameter div such as

```html
<div class="my-class additional-class"><div class="my-class2">
<div class="my-class"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

and I would like to get all the content of the first div, without the first div.

```html
<div class="my-class2">
<div class="my-class"></div>
</div>
```

Normally, I'd guess

```
<div.*>(.*)<\/div>/mU
```

should have worked but I'm not sure why it doesn't.

I've came across [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42486282/5324957)

```
(?s)(?<=<div\sclass="test">\n).*(?=<\/div>)
```

which works with a class name `test` but I couldn't make it work as

```
(?s)(?<=<div.*>\n)(.*)(?=<\/div>)
```

Comment: Better you use `DOM` parser

Comment: DOM parser is my second option. I don't think it would work as good as regex in this matter.

Comment: And why don't you think it would work as good as a regex in this matter? Considering that regular expressions are generally not capable enough to process the html language? And considering that a DOM parser _is_ capable of that?

Comment: DOM parser doesn't work and needs time to figure out the correct encoding in some cases. You would need to figure out `mb_detect_encoding` and `mb_convert_encoding`. Also some users don't install XML on their server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to get it using `DOM` parser:

```sh
<?php
$html = '<div class="my-class additional-class"><div class="my-class2">
<div class="my-class"></div>
</div>
</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$elems = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div'); // find all div elements
$outerdiv = $elems->item(0); // outermost div
echo $outerdiv->childNodes[0]->C14N() . "\n"; // print inner HTML

/*
<div class="my-class2">
<div class="my-class"></div>
</div>
*/
?>
```

If you really want a regex solution then use:

```
~<div[^>]*>(.*)</div>~is
```

and grab capture group #1.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `.*`, you should use `[\s\S]*` to match every character including new lines.

Here's a working example:

```
<div.*?>([\s\S]*)<\/div>
```

See the [test case](https://regex101.com/r/OavpdR/1/)

---

Also if you want the tags must to be balanced, you could try this with recursion `(?R)`:

```
<div.*?>((?:(?!<\/?div)[\s\S]|(?R))*)<\/div>
```

See the [test case](https://regex101.com/r/PxyvWM/1/), notice it's not match the last `</div>` since there's no corresponding opening tag for it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use non-greedy solution:

```
<div.*?>(.*)</div>
```