# svg as child of div causes unwanted shift

Tags: html, svg

If I put an svg as a child of a div, it causes the div to have an unwanted shift, unless both divs have the svg.  I cannot figure out from the dev tools where the extra space is coming from.

example:

```
    <div>
      <div class="box1">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none">
          <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="0" y2="20" stroke="#D35A5A"></line>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
      </div>
    </div>
```

```css
.box1 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #FDFDFD60;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  outline-offset: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.box2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #FDFDFD60;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  outline-offset: 2px;
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body style="background:#000000;">
    <div>
      <div class="box1">
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="box1">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none">
          <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="0" y2="20" stroke="#D35A5A"></line>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="box1">
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none">
          <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="0" y2="20" stroke="#D35A5A"></line>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="box1">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none">
          <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="0" y2="20" stroke="#D35A5A"></line>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none">
          <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="0" y2="20" stroke="#D35A5A"></line>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here's a jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/c2nwqe1m/

Comment: Use  display:block for the svg elements

Comment: thanks @enxaneta, that worked as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an inline element `<svg>` could cause baseline changes. Assigning `.box1` and `.box2` the same `vertical-align` could solve this issue:

```css
.box1, .box2 {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
.box1, .box2 {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.box1 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #FDFDFD60;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  outline-offset: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.box2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #FDFDFD60;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  outline-offset: 2px;
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body style="background:#000000;">
    <div>
      <div class="box1">
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="box1">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none">
          <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="0" y2="20" stroke="#D35A5A"></line>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="box1">
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none">
          <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="0" y2="20" stroke="#D35A5A"></line>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="box1">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none">
          <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="0" y2="20" stroke="#D35A5A"></line>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none">
          <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="0" y2="20" stroke="#D35A5A"></line>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: ++ to this great answer. [May I bring your attention to this question, that you have answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67481743/548225). I left a comment long time back that dupe is not correct. Please consider reopening if you agree.